# Google Apps Script API iterate/ loop through ID individually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have an endpoint that i need to go through X number of times (dependent on how many IDs), Each call will need to assign its individual LineItem ID and bring back a JSON response.

I have tried the following code, and it seems I can call the API but can't seem to figure out how to translate the response back to my sheet, so in the case below i may have upto 10 LI ids that will need to be called up individually > results brought back> copied to last row of a particular range and then the next API call with the next LI id, etc...

```
function ListLI360API_Agetest(){


  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('MySheet');
  var adID = 1558211;
  var LIs =sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);
  var LIArrayLength = LIs.length;

    for (var i = 0; i <= LIArrayLength; i++) {

    if(LIs[i]!== undefined){
      var url = 'https://displayvideo.googleapis.com/v1/advertisers/'+adID+'/lineItems/'+LIs[i]+'/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions'

  //Logger.log(url);
  var response = callApi5 (url, 'GET');
  //Logger.log(response);
  var content = response.getContentText();
  //Logger.log(content);
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  //Logger.log(json);
  var ageData = json["assignedTargetingOptions"];
  //Logger.log(ageData);
   
  var rows = [],
      data;
  for (i = 0; i <= ageData.length; i++) {
        data = ageData[i];
        rows.push([data.name]);
      }
      //save results to spreadsheet in the next blank column and then API for next LI ID
      Logger.log(rows);
  
    }
  }//endfor
}
```

I seem to be getting stuck on reading the results, i have tried with the following added into the script above but i get an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined", im guessing there are some nulls/ blanks being returned in the JSON and hence it cant read the length

JSON looks like...

```
[20-06-24 21:34:57:159 BST] {
  "assignedTargetingOptions": [
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917016/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503004",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503004",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_45_54",
        "targetingOptionId": "503004"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917016/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503005",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503005",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_55_64",
        "targetingOptionId": "503005"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917016/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503006",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503006",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_65_PLUS",
        "targetingOptionId": "503006"
      }
    }
  ]
}

[20-06-24 21:34:57:694 BST] {
  "assignedTargetingOptions": [
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917017/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503004",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503004",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_45_54",
        "targetingOptionId": "503004"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917017/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503005",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503005",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_55_64",
        "targetingOptionId": "503005"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "advertisers/1558211/lineItems/36917017/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions/503006",
      "assignedTargetingOptionId": "503006",
      "targetingType": "TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE",
      "inheritance": "NOT_INHERITED",
      "ageRangeDetails": {
        "ageRange": "AGE_RANGE_65_PLUS",
        "targetingOptionId": "503006"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From this Example there are 2 LI Ids so 2 separate outputs, i need to take parts of these outputs and print them into the spreadsheet

API function looks like...

```
function callApi5(url, methodType, requestBody) {
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
  var headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept' :'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getService().getAccessToken()
  };
  var options = {
      method: methodType,
      headers : headers,
      muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  if (requestBody) {
    options.payload = requestBody;
  }
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  }
}


function getService() {
  // Create a new service with the given name. The name will be used when
  // persisting the authorized token, so ensure it is unique within the
  // scope of the property store.
  return OAuth2.createService('MyService')

      // Set the endpoint URLs, which are the same for all Google services.
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')
      

      // Set the client ID and secret, from the Google Developers Console.
      .setClientId("xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com")
      .setClientSecret("xxxxxx")

      // Set the name of the callback function in the script referenced
      // above that should be invoked to complete the OAuth flow.
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

      // Set the scopes to request (space-separated for Google services).
      // this is blogger read only scope for write access is:
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/display-video')
      // Below are Google-specific OAuth2 parameters.

      // Sets the login hint, which will prevent the account chooser screen
      // from being shown to users logged in with multiple accounts.
      .setParam('login_hint', 'xxxx@xxxs.com')
      
      // Requests offline access.
      .setParam('access_type', 'offline')

      // Forces the approval prompt every time. This is useful for testing,
      // but not desirable in a production application.
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');
}
```

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: Json looks like this (in this instance there are 2 LI IDs so i get 2 responses), i need to read some of the info from both responses one after another and copy them into the spreadhseet

Comment: Looks like what?

Comment: sorry added above into main question^^

Comment: What does `callApi5` look like?

Comment: functions added above^

Comment: Hi @ImdadRahman - please, in the future, do not use code snippets tool if the snippet cannot be run right here and now (use code blocks, one can use Ctrl + K for convenience). SO has no setup for Google Apps Script to be run. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from all requests, which used the URLs created by `'https://displayvideo.googleapis.com/v1/advertisers/'+adID+'/lineItems/'+LIs[i]+'/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions'`, and put them to the Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer? From your question, I thought that your script of `callApi5()` works and `json` of `var json = JSON.parse(content);` is the value you showed in your question. So I would like to propose to modify the function of `ListLI360API_Agetest`.

#### Modification points:

- When the array is used in the for loop, please loop from `0` to `array.length - 1`. Because the 1st index of array is `0`. So, when `for (var i = 0; i <= LIArrayLength; i++)` is used, an error occurs at the last loop of `LIArrayLength`. In this case, please modify to `for (var i = 0; i < LIArrayLength; i++)`. Also, this can be said for `for (i = 0; i <= ageData.length; i++) {`.
- In your script, 1 for loop is included in the for loop. And, each loop uses the variable `i`. In this case, the variables of `i` of each loop are affected. By this, the loop cannot be correctly worked.

  - I think that your error of `TypeError: Cannot read property "name" from undefined` might be due to above 2 points.
- `LIs` of `var LIs =sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);` is 2 dimensional array. So in this case, I think that `LIs[i][0]` is suitable instead of `LIs[i]`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script, and set the destination sheet name to the last line of `ss.getSheetByName("###").getRange(1, 10, result.length, 1).setValues(result);`.

```
function ListLI360API_Agetest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');  // Modified
  var adID = 1558211;
  var LIs = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);
  var LIArrayLength = LIs.length;
  var result = [];  // Added
  for (var i = 0; i < LIArrayLength; i++) {  // Modified
    if (LIs[i][0] !== undefined) {  // Modified
      var url = 'https://displayvideo.googleapis.com/v1/advertisers/'+adID+'/lineItems/'+LIs[i][0]+'/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions'  // Modified
      var response = callApi5 (url, 'GET');
      var content = response.getContentText();
      var json = JSON.parse(content);
      var ageData = json["assignedTargetingOptions"];
      for (var j = 0; j < ageData.length; j++) {  // Modified
        var data = ageData[j];
        result.push([data.name]);  // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  // Please set the destination sheet name.
  ss.getSheetByName("###").getRange(1, 1, result.length, 1).setValues(result);  // Added
}
```

- If `data.name` is not existing, you don't want to put the values, please modify `result.push([data.name]);` to `if (data.name) result.push([data.name]);`.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that the structure of JSON object retrieved from each URL is the same. If the structure is different for each URL created by `LIs[i][0]`, it is required to modify the script. Please be careful this.
- I couldn't understand the result situation that the values are put to the Spreadsheet from your question. So in this modified script, the values are put to the destination sheet. If this is different from your actual situation, please modify the script.

#### References:

- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the answer provided by Tanike and modified the last part to be able to print to the spreadsheet. I have added a few more fields from JSON to test this, and finally added:

```
dataRange = sheet.getRange(lr+1, 17, result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
```

to print onto the spreadhseet.

```
function ListLI360API_Agetest(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('MySheet');  // Modified
  var adID = 1558211;
  var LIs = sheet.getRange(2, 3, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);
  var LIArrayLength = LIs.length;
  var result = [];  // Added
  var lr = sheet.getRange('Q1').getDataRegion().getLastRow(); //Added
  for (var i = 0; i < LIArrayLength; i++) {  // Modified
    if (LIs[i][0] !== undefined) {  // Modified
      var url = 'https://displayvideo.googleapis.com/v1/advertisers/'+adID+'/lineItems/'+LIs[i][0]+'/targetingTypes/TARGETING_TYPE_AGE_RANGE/assignedTargetingOptions'  // Modified
      var response = callApi5 (url, 'GET');
      var content = response.getContentText();
      var json = JSON.parse(content);
      var ageData = json["assignedTargetingOptions"];
      for (var j = 0; j < ageData.length; j++) {  // Modified
        var data = ageData[j];
        result.push([
        data.name,
        data.assignedTargetingOptionId,
        data.ageRangeDetails.ageRange]);  // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  // Each Set of results is pushed one after another
  dataRange = sheet.getRange(lr+1, 17, result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);//Modified

}
```

Comment: Imdad, also please note that SO is not a traditional forum, and answers should not attempt to communicate with other answers, this is not a forum. The reason I warn you is because such answers tend to be flagged as "Not An Answer" (NAA) and simply deleted. Yours seems a valid addition to Tanaike's answer, so I edited it into shape